# How to get Value of entity Cabang ? How Hibernate Work?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

[Why my value put on hibernate interceptor? and to get it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmmUd.jpg)

[I cannot get the value of Cabang event I request from service (query select)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWwIX.png)

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are trying to do and in what way it doesn't work. Please describe your problem in some detail, including what you tried to solve the problem.

Comment: cabangSelected = cabangService.findOneById(konsumen.getIdCabang());
when i hit the service the return of it in hibernateInterceptor.